Line of bestfit made using using polyfit in python is in entirely the wrong place
Im trying to plot a graph using two numpy arrays of data which should be directly proportional in Python, however when I use the polyfit function to try and plot a line of bestfit, the line is no where near the data and the gradient doesnt reflect the data either.
Ive put the data into excel and plotted a graph and line of bestfit and its exactly how you would expect, so I'm not sure why its not working in python? I would be very grateful for any help, I've attached this section of my code below.
#Creating another graph to plot final data
fig2, ax2=plt.subplots()
fig2, plt.scatter(1/Lengths*2, average_frequencies)
ax2.set_xlabel("1/Length$^2$(m$^-$$^2$)")
ax2.set_ylabel("Frequency(Hz)")
ax2.set_title("Length against Frequency graph")

#Add line of best fit to plot
average_frequencies=np.array(average_frequencies, dtype=float)
G,c=np.polyfit(1/Lengths*2, average_frequencies, 1) #G is the gradient, c is Y-intercept
ax2.plot(1/Lengths*2, (G/Lengths*2)+c, color='red', label='Line of bestfit')

The graph that it produces
